# Can't access default k3s metrics server from Prometheus-Adapter

Tags: prometheus, metrics, k3s

I have installed Prometheus-adapter along with the default metrics-server that comes with k3s securely on port 4443.

Unfortunately, I get no resources when I query custom.metrics.k8s.io

```
$  kubectl get --raw "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1" | jq .
{
  "kind": "APIResourceList",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "groupVersion": "custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "resources": []
}
```

When I look at the logs of Prometheus-adapter I get unable to update list of all metrics: unable to fetch metrics for query ...: x509: certificate is valid for localhost, localhost, not metrics-server.kube-system

My metrics server arguments are as follows

```
      - args:                                                                                                                                                                                 
        - --cert-dir=/tmp                                                                                                                                                                     
        - --secure-port=4443                                                                                                                                                                  
        - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP                                                                                                                                        
        - --kubelet-use-node-status-port                                                                                                                                                      
        - --metric-resolution=45s
```

How can I resolve this issue?